# Progress is displayed only for the last item in the queue. ngFileUpload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I'm using AngularJS (1.2.28) and [**ng-file-upload** directive](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) (7.0.17). On the backend there's a **WCF service** hosted in **IIS 7**.

I'm trying to display a progress bar per uploaded file and here's my code:

**uploadsController**

```
controller('uploadsController', ['$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {
    $scope.upload = [];

    $scope.select = function(files) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
            files[i].progress = 0;
        }
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
            var $file = $scope.files[i];
            (function(index) {
                $scope.upload[index] = Upload.upload({
                url: "/documents-manager/UploadsService.svc/upload", 
                    method: "POST",
                    file: $file
                }).progress(function(evt) {
                    $file.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                });
            })(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**corresponding markup**

```
<div ngf-select="select($files)" ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true">search</div>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in files">
        <td>
            <div>{{ file.name }}</div>
            <div class="progress">
                <span class="meter" style="width:{{ file.progress }}%;"</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**the problem**

The progress is getting displayed only for the last file in the queue. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$file variable that you are using to set the progress is being overwritten by the last file that's why you see the progress on the last file. Use the index to access the correct file instead:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
        var $file = $scope.files[i];
        (function(index) {
            $scope.upload[index] = Upload.upload({
            url: "/documents-manager/UploadsService.svc/upload", 
                method: "POST",
                file: $file
            }).progress(function(evt) {
                $scope.files[index].progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            });
        })(i);
    }
```